# fast java/python/C++ ipc

Tags: java, c++, python, ipc, rpc

I notice this thread: [Fastish Python/Jython IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163574/fast-ish-python-jython-ipc), and I have a similar problem, but in different language.

I have a Java front-end and a C++ back-end, which I am thinking about rewrite it in Python in some near future. What will be the best IPC? I prefer socket to HTTP, as I am trying to avoid the HTTP overhead. And XML-RPC is an example one to avoid!

Are there any library to deal with cross platform RPC (JSON/XML etc.)?

Newbie in this field, thanks ahead!

Comment: to answer the question "Are there any library to deal with cross platform RPC (JSON/XML etc.)?" yes XML-RPC is a good choice. SOAP should be avoided but XML-RPC is pretty lightweight.

Comment: Why do you limit solutions by not including XML-RPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the C++ backend you can use [xmlrpc++](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/) (LGPL'ed) - I'm planning to use it myself. It has very clean code so you can modify it easily if you need to.

As for the frontends in Java/Python, you could make use of [Apache XML-RPC](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) (don't know anything about it) or Python's [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) (very easy to use).

XML-RPC should be cross-platform. I've tried xmlrpc++ as server and xmlrpclib as client and it seems to work correctly, even when using faults, i.e. passing errors to the client.